# Performating mathematical operations with sparse matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with huge sparse matrices (100000X100000) on python using `scipy.sparse` library specifically the csr format, But I don't know to iterate through a sparse matrix & apply some mathematical operations (subtraction, multiplication and addition) on the matrix's (non-zero) elements.
since its impossible to work on the matrix in its normal form. Can someone please explain how can I perform that and how can I access the elements while they're in their sparse form?

My main purpose is performing basic Gaussian Elimination on the csr and obtain LU from it, can someone please guide me through this issue?

Comment: Are you using `scipy.sparse`, I assume? State so, if that's the case :)

Comment: Study the attributes and methods of the `scipy.spare` matrix format, especially the `csr`.  You need to be more specific about the problems that are encountering.  At this point we can only guess as to your understanding of the issues.

Comment: Use the LU solver in scipy? Generally you don't want to actually do the full LU decomposition cause it's way less sparse than the original.

Comment: Use the the provided linear algebra methods, `https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html`.  Doing your own Gaussian elimination would be awkward and slow even with dense arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the recommendation, I need to implement the LU on sparse matrices from scratch as a part of a course I'm studying.

Comment: @martineau I haven't found any tutorial that actually helped me in this specific issue, also I have read the documentation but it doesn't answer my questions. based on your comment I assume that an answer for my questions exists, can you link documentation page where iterating through scipy csr is mentioned?

Comment: It is possible to iterate on a `csr` by iterating on the `indptr`, using that to fetch `indices` and `data` for a single row.  Some previous SO have demonstrated this.  Otherwise, `csr` uses matrix multiplication with an `extractor` matrix to do indexing.  That's significantly slower than `ndarray` indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj that's exactly what I want, can you please link a page or a video or a script that I can learn from? I really haven't found anything

Comment: No I can't because I have't looked a tutorials in ages.  But a SO search on `[scipy]` and `indptr` might be productive.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you very much! I looked up what you suggested and I kind of implemented a GE algorithm on my sparse matrix! the values are wrong ( I will fix that tomorrow) but the Iteration part worked perfectly thanks to you ^^